# Interchanging sum and integral when dominated convergence fails

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f=\sum_{n >2} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n \log n}$. Now  $\sum \int_{[0, 2\pi]} |\sin(nx)|/(n \log n)$ does not converge because it is exactly $C\sum 1/(n\log n)$ which does not converge, so I can't apply dominated convergence theorem.  I know this converges uniformly on every compact that doesn't contain $0$. How can I conclude that sum and integration commute?

---

edit:
Sorry I was not thinking. I want to integrate from $[0,2\pi]$.  My main issue is what to do, because $[0,2\pi]$ contains $0$.  Now on $E=[0,2\pi]\setminus ([0,\epsilon] \cup [\pi-\epsilon, \pi +\epsilon] \cup [2\pi-\epsilon,2\pi])$ I know that the series converges uniformly, by using Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence, or just by arguing from first principles using summation by parts. Thus $\int_E$ commutes with the sum. It takes some work to show that the series converges uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$.  But I think it should be possible to proceed without having uniform convergence on $([0,\epsilon] \cup [\pi-\epsilon, \pi +\epsilon] \cup [2\pi-\epsilon,2\pi])$. My question then is how to do it.

Comment: the torus.   The functions are 1-periodic extensions of the restrictions to $0-1$.

Comment: Or just integrate from $[0,1]$ if you like.

Comment: You probably want to use a few facts about Fourier series. The coefficients $1/(n\log n)$ are in $\ell^2$, so the series converges in $L^2$ and thus also in $L^1$, and this gives that $\int f = \widehat{f}(0)=0$.

Comment: Sorry I was not thinking. I want to integrate from $[0,2\pi]$.  My main issue is what to do, because $[0,2\pi]$ contains $0$.  Now on $[\epsilon, 2\pi -\epsilon]$ I know that the series converges uniformly, by using dirichlet's test for uniform convergence, or just by arguing from first principles using summation by parts.Thus $\int_{[\epsilon, 2\pi -\epsilon]}$ commutes with the sum. It takes some work to show that the series converges uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$.  But I think it should be possible to proceed without having uniform convergence on $[0,\epsilon]$. My question then is how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$ g_k(x) = \sum_{n=3}^k \frac{sin(nx)}{n\log(n)} $$ 
It sounds to me like you are saying that  you already know the following: Over any interval $[a,b]$ that does not contain 0, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $K$ such that $|g_k(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and all $k\geq K$. Is this correct?  That is how I interpret " I know this converges uniformly on every compact that doesn't contain 0."

In that case, let $[a,b]$ be an interval such that $0 < a < b< 2\pi$.  fix $\epsilon \in (0,\pi)$ and choose $K$ as above. Then for all $k \geq K$: 
$$ \left|\int_a^b [g_k(x)-f(x)]dx\right| \leq \int_a^b |g_k(x)-f(x)|dx \leq (b-a)\epsilon $$

But $\int_a^b g_k(x) dx = \sum_{n=3}^k\frac{-\cos(nb)+\cos(na)}{n^2\log(n)}$, which certainly converges as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

So then for any interval $[a,b]$ that does not contain 0 we get: 
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{-\cos(nb)+\cos(na)}{n^2\log(n)}$$

---

If you want to fix $\epsilon>0$ and take $b=2\pi-\epsilon$ and $a=\epsilon$ then: 
$$ \int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} f(x)dx = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{-\cos(n(2\pi-\epsilon))+\cos(n\epsilon)}{n^2\log(n)}$$
Because the summation is of terms that decay like $1/n^2$, there seems to be no trouble taking $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$ on the right-hand-side:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} f(x)dx = 0 $$

In view of the comments below, it is not obvious how to prove the left-hand-side is equal to $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx$.

---

Taking a hint from Christian Remling’s comment on $L^2$ and Fourier series: 
Let $[a,b]$ be an interval such that $0<a<b<2\pi$.  Fix $\epsilon>0$, let $k\geq 3$ be such that $|g_k(t)-f(t)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.  We know that for any real numbers $a,b$ we have $a^2 \leq 4b^2 + 4(a-b)^2$.  So: 
\begin{align}
&\int_a^b f(t)^2dt \\
&\leq \int_a^b[4g_k(t)^2 + 4(f(t)-g_k(t))^2]dt \\
&\leq 4\int_a^b g_k(t)^2dt + 4(b-a)\epsilon^2\\
&\leq 4\int_0^{2\pi}g_k(t)^2dt + 4(2\pi)\epsilon^2  \\
&= 4\sum_{n=3}^k \frac{\pi}{(n\log(n))^2} + 8\pi \epsilon^2 
\end{align}
where the final equality holds by orthogonality of the $\sin(nx)$ functions. 
Thus, there is a finite constant $C$ (independent of $[a,b]$) such that: 
$$ \int_a^b f(t)^2dt \leq C $$
By the monotone convergence theorem, it follows that $\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)^2dt \leq C$. Hence, $\int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|dt < \infty$ (by Cauchy-Schwarz).  So the integrals of $f(t)^+$ and $f(t)^-$ exist and are finite. It follows again by the monotone convergence theorem that: 
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} f(x)dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx $$ 
and the right-hand-side is 0 by the last equation in the previous section of this answer.

Comment: However, you're avoiding the main issue: what about $\int_0^a g_k$?

Comment: Why do you know $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{[\epsilon, 2\pi - \epsilon]} f(x) dx =\int_{[0,2\pi]} f(x) dx$?  For example if we knew $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, then we could say$lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{[0,2\pi]} f \chi_{[0,2\pi]-([0,\epsilon)\cup (1-\epsilon,1])}=\int_{[0,2\pi]} f lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \chi_{[0,2\pi]-([0,\epsilon)\cup (1-\epsilon,1])}=\int_{[0,2\pi]} f$ where the second equality is by DCT, dominating by $f$.  Do we know this?

Comment: Sorry the first equality is by dominated convergence.

Comment: not the second(in my comment)

Comment: Where the second equality is the second equality of the second equation.

Comment: @user062295 Aha.  Good question.  I thought it was "obvious" that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1f(t)dt = \int_0^1 f(t)dt$, though showing it does not seem immediate right now.  In general I think that for any function $h:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\int_{\epsilon}^1 h(t)dt$ exists for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_{\epsilon}^1h(t)dt = c$, then $\int_0^1 h(t)dt=c$. Will think about how to show it...

Comment: Part of my conjecture above about general functions $h(t)$ can be shown by the monotone convergence theorem applied separately to $h^+(t)$ and $h^-(t)$.  What we get is $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^1 h^+(t)dt = \int_0^1 h^+(t)dt$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^1 h^-(t)dt = \int_0^1 h^-(t)dt$.  The only difficulty is when $\int_0^1 h^+(t)dt=\int_0^1 h^-(t)dt=\infty$, since it leads to the undefined case $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: Okay when $\int_0^1 h^+(t)dt = \int_0^1 h^-(t)dt = \infty$ then I can come up with a counter-example to my own conjecture by defining $h$ oscillatory such that for large $k$ it has integrals $\int_{1/(2k+1)}^{1/(2k)}h(t)dt=1/k$ and $\int_{1/(2k+2)}^{1/(2k+1)}h(t)dt = -1/k$.  In that case $\int_0^1 h(t)dt$ is not defined. I will add a comment in my answer above to be more careful.

Comment: Taking a hint from Christian Remling's comment, we see that if $\int_0^1 h(t)^2dt < \infty$ then $\int_0^1 |h(t)|dt < \infty$ (by Cauchy-Schwartz) and so the integrals of $h^+(t)$ and $h^-(t)$ are both finite.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest in my problem.  I think once you know $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, (since it is in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$), then tonelli's theorem implies the sequence of functions $\{sin(n\pi x)/(n logn)\}_n$ is in $L^1(\T \times \Z, \mu \times \text{counting measure})$, so that fubini's theorem gives that the two sums interchange, so you don't need the earlier part of the answer.  I would have upvoted your answer if I had enough stackexchange reputation.